# PIL Python Module throwing error when saving image with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Whenever I try to save an image selected from tkinter, I get an error like this:

```
    raise ValueError("unknown file extension: {}".format(ext)) from e
ValueError: unknown file extension:
```

I'm using tkinter to open up the file browser to select an image file. The user can choose to flip the image horizontally and vertically. After that, they can choose to save as a variety of image formats. However, this returns the above error. I don't really see what is wrong. The name variable in the save() function contains the name after the file is picked. PIL's save function should be able to take that name and save it in the current working directory.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image


def open_image():
    global img
    img = Image.open(
        filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*"))))
    save_button.config(bg=default_color)
    flip_horizontal_button.config(bg=default_color)
    flip_vertical_button.config(bg=default_color)


def flip_horizontal():
    global img
    if img:
        img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)


def flip_vertical():
    global img
    if img:
        img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)


def save():
    global img
    if img:
        #os.chdir("/")
        default_name = "Untitled"
        """ print(default_name+"."+img.format)
        print(os.path.isfile(default_name+"."+img.format))
        print(os.path)
        if os.path.isfile(default_name+"."+img.format):
            expand = 1
            while True:
                expand += 1
                expanded_name = default_name+str(expand)
                if os.path.isfile(expanded_name):
                    continue
                else:
                    default_name = expanded_name
                    break"""
        name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save As", filetypes=(
            ('JPEG', ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.jpe')), ('PNG', '*.png'), ('GIF', '*.gif')),
                                            initialfile=default_name+"."+img.format)
        img.save(name)


img = None

root = Tk()
root.title("Meme Deep Fryer")
root.geometry('600x500')
default_color = root.cget('bg')

open_button = Button(text='Open Image', font=('Arial', 20), command=open_image)
flip_horizontal_button = Button(text='Flip Horizontal', font=('Arial', 10), command=flip_horizontal, bg="gray")
flip_vertical_button = Button(text='Flip Vertical', font=('Arial', 10), command=flip_vertical, bg="gray")
save_button = Button(text='Save', font=('Arial', 20), command=save, bg="gray")

open_button.pack(anchor='nw', side=LEFT)
save_button.pack(anchor='nw', side=LEFT)
flip_horizontal_button.pack(anchor='w')
flip_vertical_button.pack(anchor='w')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error said that you tried to save to a filename without extension.

Comment: You can use defaultextension option to prevent human error

Comment: @EricMathieu how to a set the default extension to be the images extension when it was uploaded

Comment: also, if the program is saving a filename without an extension, what is the filetypes=(file types) supposed to do then? isn't the selected filetype supposed to automatically go as the extension?

Comment: @JamesHuang: Since you use Path you can use Path(your_path).suffix  update your open_image to get your filname, save the extension as a global and then open the image.

Comment: file types are used to filer which files are displayes.

Comment: Then you should set `defaultextension` option of `asksaveasfilename()`.

Comment: can i have a full code that shows how everything is supposed to turn out in the end?

Comment: I tried setting default extenstion = "png" but it doesn't autofill. Is there a way I can save it with an autofill of let's say "Untitled.png" or something

Comment: Did you try `name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Select file", defaultextension='', filetypes=...)`? It will use the first extension selected in the `Save as type:` dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass argument `typevariable` in `asksaveasfilename`:

```
ext = tkinter.StringVar()
name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Select file", typevariable=ext, filetypes=(('JPEG', ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.jpe')), ('PNG', '*.png'), ('BMP', ('*.bmp', '*.jdib')), ('GIF', '*.gif')))

if name: 
    img.save(os.path.basename(name)+"."+ext.get().lower()) # splice the string and the extension.
```

Comment: It still doesn't quite work for me. What I want is that the user can delete the extension that was filled in and still save it with a string that the program can end with an extension.  I tried this and it doesn't really make a difference in the outcome. If you try saving this webpage and then delete the default file name and then save the computer will already put the file extension for you. Is there a way to do that? I've updated my code to show that I've gotten an extension prefilled in to work.

Comment: @JamesHuang In my example, user only need to input the name of the file,then it will automatically add the extension the user has selected.

Comment: Oh I tried it now and it works! Is there a way to get the image to save in the folder that I selected in the askfilename because os is just saving it into the cwd for me

Comment: @JamesHuang Yes,just remove the `os.path.basename`.You shouldn't use it.That's will return just the file name not the full path.